# How can I export Ethereum blockchain data into csv?

Tags: transactions, mining

I would like to download the Ethereum blockchain and use the data for machine learning purposes. For this, I have to get the data into a workable format like csv or a flat JSON etc.

I've read about approaches and the most common one seems to be through a monkeyDB. Do you know a source code that implements this method? Or do you know other methods that could be used to get the Ethereum blockchain data into a modeling friendly format?

Thanks!

Comment: Not exactly a CSV but can be relevant https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28990/how-do-i-export-ethereum-blocks-with-quickblocks-to-a-json-file

Answer (score 3):

Here is an article on how to export Ethereum data to csv and analyze it with Amazon Athena https://medium.com/@medvedev1088/exporting-and-analyzing-ethereum-blockchain-f5353414a94e

It uses https://github.com/medvedev1088/ethereum-etl which outputs the data into `blocks.csv`, `transactions.csv`, `erc20_transfers.csv`.

`blocks.csv`

```
Column                  | Type               |
------------------------|---------------------
block_number            | bigint             |
block_hash              | hex_string         |
block_parent_hash       | hex_string         |
block_nonce             | hex_string         |
block_sha3_uncles       | hex_string         |
block_logs_bloom        | hex_string         |
block_transactions_root | hex_string         |
block_state_root        | hex_string         |
block_miner             | hex_string         |
block_difficulty        | bigint             |
block_total_difficulty  | bigint             |
block_size              | bigint             |
block_extra_data        | hex_string         |
block_gas_limit         | bigint             |
block_gas_used          | bigint             |
block_timestamp         | bigint             |
block_transaction_count | bigint             |
```

`transactions.csv`

```
Column              |    Type     |
--------------------|--------------
tx_hash             | hex_string  |
tx_nonce            | bigint      |
tx_block_hash       | hex_string  |
tx_block_number     | bigint      |
tx_index            | bigint      |
tx_from             | hex_string  |
tx_to               | hex_string  |
tx_value            | bigint      |
tx_gas              | bigint      |
tx_gas_price        | bigint      |
tx_input            | hex_string  |
```

`erc20_transfers.csv`

```
Column              |    Type     |
--------------------|--------------
erc20_token         | hex_string  |
erc20_from          | hex_string  |
erc20_to            | hex_string  |
erc20_value         | bigint      |
erc20_tx_hash       | hex_string  |
erc20_block_number  | bigint      |
```

Answer (score 1):

To export Ethereum data, you may rely on a number of public nodes listed at [ethereumnodes.com](https://ethereumnodes.com): some of them are free of charge.

They provide access to [JSON RPC API](https://ethereum.github.io/execution-apis/api-documentation/) which allows you to export blocks, transactions and other blockchain data in JSON.

Here is a modern approach to export the full history of Ethereum into S3 using the public nodes: [“How to Export a Full History of Ethereum Blockchain to S3”](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-dump-full-ethereum-history-to-s3-296fb3ad175) (Medium).

As an alternative, you may rely on [BigQuery public datasets](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery(cameo:product/ethereum/crypto-ethereum-blockchain)) with Ethereum data. This will free your hands from exporting the data. Using BigQuery datasets is also covered by the article.